# Ubuntu 19.04 nvidia drivers not working at all, NVIDIA GeForce GTX-1050 Ti 4GB

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 19.04, nouveau, gpu-driver

I have a gaming laptop ASUS ROG GL703Ge STRIX with the mentioned Nvidia GPU, I installed ubuntu with windows as dual boot but the problem I'm facing is I can't use the GPU, I tried installing the drivers with `sudo ubuntu-drivers auto-install` it installed **nvidia-driver-430** which is the one recommended by Nvidia website, but when I type `nvidia-smi` I get an error message saying :

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

then I removed the driver and installed it manually:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-430 nvidia-settings
```

but still the same issue, what can I do to solve this?

And also before I boot each time I have to press e in the grub menu to edit the code and to add `nouveau.modeset=0`.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: it's disabled, no results

Comment: What is the output of `prime-select query`?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you haven't actually switched to using your nvidia driver. Go to Software and Updates and then to the Additional Drivers tab and select your installed nvidia driver there instead of the open source one which is enabled by default. Then do

```
prime-select nvidia
reboot
```

Then when after reboot you should be able to run nvidia-smi correctly. Use prime-select to switch between intel and nvidia and then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a matter of updrading the Kernel (in sudo)

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-kernel-to-latest-version-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

then do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Finally install the driver and reboot

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall  
sudo reboot
```